# how to pass user input from one html page to another using local storage

Tags: local-storage

I have tried searching other links but did not find any solution.

I have this particular code

```
 <input type= "text" id="tname" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
 <input type="text" id="tcontact" placeholder="Enter Contact No."/>
 <input type="text" id="temail" placeholder="Enter Email"/>
 <input type="text" id="tgender" placeholder="Enter Gender"/>
 <input type="text" id="tqual" placeholder="Enter qualification"/>
 <input type="submit" id="display" value="Display"/>
```

I want to pass these user inputs to another page and just display them using local storage.

The javascript code which I have used here is as follows

```
  function connector_id(global)
   {
    var sname =document.getElementById("tname");
    var scontact =document.getElementById("tcontact");
    var semail =document.getElementById("temail");
    var sgender =document.getElementById("tgender");
    var squal =document.getElementById("tqual");

    localStorage.sname = sname;
    localStorage.scontact = scontact;
    localStorage.semail = semail;
    localStorage.sgender = sgender;
    localStorage.squal = squal;
  }
```

how should i use these localStorage variables to access the user input in the second page. this is where i am facing problem. dont know how to do it.

i have also found this particular code in context to my search but didnt understand this following code

```
  (function (global) {
  document.getElementById("display").addEventListener("click", function () {
       global.localStorage.setItem("mySharedData",document.getElementById("output").value);
}, false);}(window));
```

Comment: remove all the formatting elements (all the `<div>` tags) from your example code -- they make it unnecessarily hard to read.

Comment: When you talk about using local storage, also provide the js-part with which you are actually trying to implement it.

Comment: you have written "please help me" three times in your post and one time in your comment -- I removed all of them from your post, because they distract from the question. StackOverflow is all about helping each other, so no need to repeat it **four** times; in fact, StackOverflow actively discourages phrases like these in questions.

Comment: Nevertheless, it  might be easier to help you if you explain where you're actually having a problem -- you seem to have an approach of storing these things, but you don't say what's wrong with that and why you can't display stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way you store in localstorage. Check this :

```
localStorage.setItem('sname', document.getElementById("tname"));
localStorage.setItem('scontact', document.getElementById("tcontact"));
localStorage.setItem('semail', document.getElementById("temail"));
localStorage.setItem('sgender', document.getElementById("tgender"));
localStorage.setItem('squal', document.getElementById("tqual"));
```

And to retrieve the value :

```
var sname = localStorage.getItem('sname');
var scontact = localStorage.getItem('scontact');
var semail = localStorage.getItem('semail');
var sgender = localStorage.getItem('sgender');
var squal = localStorage.getItem('squal');
```